# Can't convert/cast between template types ( couldn’t deduce template parameter )

Tags: c++, templates, template-argument-deduction

Whilst messing around with templates and static_assert, I came across the following problem

*( Below is a shortened example the problem is the same )*

```cpp
template< size_t n >
struct W {
    class X {
        public:
            /* breaks normal constructor
            template< size_t o >
            X( typename W<o>::X & y ){
                static_assert( o < n , "bad");
            };
            */

            template< size_t m >
            operator typename W<m>::X() const { 
                static_assert( n < m , "bad");
                return W<m>::X();
            };
    };
};

void func( W<6>::X y ){}

int main() {
    W<5>::X x;

    // > error: conversion from ‘X<5>’ to non-scalar type ‘X<6>’ requested
    //W<6>::X y = x; 

    // > error: error: no matching function for call to ‘W<5>::X::operator W<6>::X()
    // > note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    // > note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘m’
    //x.operator W<6>::X();

    // >  error: no matching function for call to ‘W<6>::X::X(W<5>::X&)’
    // > note:   template argument deduction/substitution failed:
    // > note:   couldn’t deduce template parameter ‘o’
    //static_cast< W<6>::X >(x);
    // similarly
    //( W<6>::X ) x;

    // End Goal:
    // > error: could not convert ‘x’ from ‘X<5>’ to ‘X<6>’
    func( x );
}
```

Simply put i'd like to be able to cast/convert `W<n>::X` objects to `W<m>::X` objects only if `n < m`.

Some additional notes

- I can't use a class of the form `X<n>` instead of `W<n>::X`
- The constructor of `W::X<n>` will be private

Comment: is the nesting of types necessary to reproduce the error?

Comment: please post the code that produces the error and the error message. Hiding the error behind a comment is not optimal as any change one has to apply to your code to reproduce the error is a source of misunderstanding and confusion

Comment: @463035818_is_not_a_number , I uncommented the main goal, but i'm also curious why each of the listed conversion methods don't work.
Additionally, modifying the example so you have `X<n>` without the nesting works fine.

Comment: ok no big deal, the question is clear as it is. It was just a suggestion for improvment

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The underlying problem is, that in nested types the template parameter can not be deduced. You can work around the problem if you provide a helper variable ( N in my example ) and use a more general template for the converting operator. You may filter out other types as `W<n>::X` with SFINAE if needed.

Here we go:

```
template< size_t n >
struct W {
    class X {
        public:
            // helper to get template parameter because it can't be deduced
            static constexpr size_t N = n; 

            template < typename T, size_t x=T::N >
                operator T() const 
                {
                    //static_assert( x < n , "bad");
                    std::cout << "Target: " << n << " Source " << x << std::endl;
                    return T(); 
                }

            X()=default;
    };   
};


void func( W<6>::X  ){}  

int main() {
    W<5>::X x;
    W<6>::X y=x; 
    x.operator W<6>::X();
    static_cast< W<6>::X >(x);
    ( W<6>::X ) x; 
    func( x ); 
}
```